# Sorting Rotated Strings of Burrows Wheeler Transform (BWT) Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently working with BWT for fun. :-)

I've learn the BWT and I think BWT isn't complicated theoretically. But, until now I don't know how actually to sort the rotated strings in real implementation.

Should I hold all rotated strings first in to an array so that I can sort them using naive sorting algorithm like Bubble Sort, Selection, or others? Someone tell me that it's bad practice, since saving N elements in to an array need more times.

So, How can I sort my rotated strings while I'm rotating the strings?

Anyone who can answer this, will be very appreciated!

Thank You In Advance!

Thompson

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer, but when I implemented a BWT algorithm for a client I used the code presented [here](http://marknelson.us/1996/09/01/bwt/) as a base.

One item of historical note, it appeared the C qsort was a lot quicker than the C++ std::sort algorithm. Someone on CodeGuru suggested using the std::stable_sort and that pushed the performance up to where the C qsort was. This was in VC6.

Also run tests to find the ideal length of string - the sorting is not linear.  I was writing a compression routine for a transmission protocol so the compression had to be enough to pay for itself.  If memory serves me right that worked about 4kb on a 733MHz machine.

Answer (score 1):

BWT is a pretty easy to implement, but its weakness is it get slower as the data to be compressed get larger.

I've been do bit a quick analysis to this algorithm and the result is (correct me if i'm wrong) it takes O(n^2) in the worst case, but can achieve constant time in the best case.

It turns out that, the much consume time for BWT is when sorting the rotated strings. Improving the sorting now day seems to be a hot issues for those who love playing with algorithms. :-)

Okay, when you are encoding the data using BWT, the first thing you should do is to place an unique character to the data. It's used to tell the encoder terminated the sorting process when it founds this character. For example: say that you want to compress string "BANANA", and the steps:

BANANA$ ANANA$B NANA$BA ANA$BAN NA$BANA A$BANAN $BANANA

Rotated strings: $BANANA

Sorting the string with an unique character (EOF) like "$BANANA" will be faster then not using any unique character.

I've been post a poor article about this algorithm...

http://philipstel.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/discussion-of-burrows-wheeler-transform-algorithm/

Comment: Modern suffix array construction (and BWT) algorithms (like SA-IS) run in linear time with very little extra space: https://code.google.com/p/ge-nong/